# Pass Strings through click EventHandler

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling

I'm trying to send 3 strings to a void/EventHandler

```
 button.Click += new DownloadGame(gameZip, gameExe, gameTitle);

private void DownloadGame(string gameZip, string gameExe, string gameTitle)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(gameExe))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already Installed!");
            }
            string GamesDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Games");
            if (!Directory.Exists(GamesDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(GamesDirectory);
            InstallGameFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Build", gameExe), gameZip, gameTitle);
```

How can I call the method with the arguments without this error?

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DownloadGame' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is your `button` a Winforms? WPF? Something else entirely? Please ad a tag to indicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting **Error CS0246.** is the `new` keyword:

```
// I N C O R R E C T
button.Click += new DownloadGame(gameZip, gameExe, gameTitle);
```

Because of the `new`, the compiler is attempting to make a new instance of a `class` named `DownloadGame`. It can't find a *class* by that name because it doesn't exist (there is only a *method* by that name, thus the error).

---

The other reason that your syntax is incorrect is that the delegate signature must match. For example, a Winforms button handler would assign like this:

```
public MainForm()
{
    buttonDownload.Click += onClickDownloadButton;
}
private void onClickDownloadButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

*Regardless* of the platform, once you type `button.Click +=`  the intellisense should offer to make a method with the correct signature.

And as far as what your code is attempting to do, handling the `Click` event is to *receive* the event and data that the `Button` class is notifying and is not intended to *send* strings or anything else.

---

The thing that would seem to make sense here is that you have already performed other UI actions to populate some of these file names. For example you may have a button or menu that invokes an "open file" flow, or a settings prompt ([example](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reeopen-dialog-00.git)).

```
private void onClickDownloadButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadGame();
}
public void DownloadGame()
{
    if (!File.Exists(gameExe))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already Installed!");
    }
    string GamesDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Games");
    if (!Directory.Exists(GamesDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(GamesDirectory);
    }
    InstallGameFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Build", gameExe), gameZip, gameTitle);
}
// These need to be populated some other 
// way before enabling buttonDownload.    
private string gameZip;
private string gameExe;
private string gameTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass string to Click event. But you can create variable/property under class where this button belong.
Also, when you are adding function to Event, you can't use 'new' keyword.

```
string gameZip, gameExe, gameTitle; // Set those variables i.e. here

button.Click += DownloadGame;

private void DownloadGame(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(gameExe))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already Installed!");
    }
    string GamesDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Games");
    if (!Directory.Exists(GamesDirectory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(GamesDirectory);
    InstallGameFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Build", gameExe), gameZip, gameTitle);   
}
```